# Folder view doesn't work?

Tags: visual-studio

So I am trying to get into C# as it is used for a lot of things.
I want folder view so that I can click on a folder and put a file in there without having to go to file explorer. The problem is, when I go to Solution explorer, click on my project, click on folder view, It does nothing. I actually don't know if it is worth it to go through all this trouble but I thought I might give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only enter folder view from the solution level (rather than project). In Solution Explorer, single click on the solution you have open. Then, click the folder view icon at the top of the Solution Explorer. This will toggle the view to folder view mode.